# php eval() get attribute of object

Tags: php, laravel

For example, post name is 'New feature'. I need to get output `Post name is New feature` using `eval()`

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$str = 'Post name is $post->name';
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
```

This code outputs `Post name is {"id":1,"name": "New feature"}->name`. How to get exactly name of post with eval, not whole object?

**NOTE**

do not pay big attention to what is outputs exactly, it was taken like abstract, i need to take attribute of object using eval, because `$str` will be dynamic

Comment: Try this : $str = 'Post name is '.$post->name;

Comment: Using `eval` in this context is just an invitation to have arbitrary code execution on your server

Comment: @apokryfos admin using editor will create different pages, so i need to get some values from db and put it to content

Comment: That doesn't explain why you think `eval` is necessary

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov in that case you can use placeholders in the content and replace them when outputting. No eval required. for example use [post.name] in the content and str replace all when outputting.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'Post name is ' . $post->name;
echo $str;
```

I don't recommend using eval()...

Comment: do not pay big attention to what is outputs exactly, it was taken like abstract, i need to take attribute of object using eval, because ```$str``` will be dynamic

Comment: In 99,9% of the cases there is an other solution than eval(). So always try to avoid it. Even if the $str is dynamic, I don't think eval will be the best, safest solution.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `$post` will be evaluated directly in the eval function. Thus outputing `{"id":1,"name": "New feature"}`. Using eval is not recommended and certainly not for outputting a simple string. You can go with this instead:

```php
$post = Post::find($id);
$str = "Post name is {$post->name}";
echo $str;
```

If you really need eval for some reason (there is probably a better way than eval), then this should do it:

```php
$post = Post::find($id);
$name = $post->name;
$str = 'Post name is'.$name;
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
```

Comment: do not pay big attention to what is outputs exactly, it was taken like abstract, i need to take attribute of object using eval, because ```$str``` will be dynamic

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov I adjusted my answer for eval usage, but I would really advise against using it. (even the php docs tell us so.)